# How to redirect to clean URL (remove last hypen) with RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: redirect

I am trying to create a clean URL using a RewriteRule in an .htaccess file.

Using a hypothetical example, I would like this:

"article0/news/Prints-Ads-newspapers-and-magazines-"

"article1/news/true-love-"

"article2/news/fire-storm-"

"article3/news/nba-news-"

To redirect to :

"article0/news/Prints-Ads-newspapers-and-magazines"

"article1/news/true-love"

"article2/news/fire-storm"

"article3/news/nba-news"

I need to remove the last hypen from this urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but after i applied this rule i am getting following behavior:

http://example.com/var/www/html/article0/news/Prints-Ads-newspapers-and-magazines 

its adding var/www/html/ for some reason.

But last hypen from this urls is removed :)

Comment: @Abraham I've changed answer. Try now. Is there anything more in your htaccess?